# test trigger msg form not working

Tags: trigger, form

I would like to test a triggered message (which is fully set up).  However, this form is not working:

http://developers.exacttarget.com/sampleapps/dotnet/triggeredsendtester/

I was logged into Code@ before I tried accessing it.  It says "There is no app configured at that hostname.  Perhaps the app owner has renamed it, or you mistyped the URL" when I click on the URL.

Has this form moved elsewhere?

Thanks!
Saad